# How to find asymptotic complexity when the function has a ceil in it ? (2^(2^ceil(log2(n)))) = O( 2^n )?

Tags: algorithm, asymptotic-complexity

I ran a program to find the difference between n + 1 and 2**ceil(log2(n+1)),where n is a power of 2 . It keeps increasing exponentially

So from the definition of Big - O, there is no constant c' such that -

```
2^(2^ceil(log2(n))) <= c' * 2^n
```

Therefore

```
(2^(2^ceil(log2(n)))) != O( 2^n )
```

Would the above statement be correct ? If yes, then how can I prove it ?

Comment: From the code you show (``f n = f1 n - f2 n``) I would say it is an O(1) operation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We need to show that, for every constant c, there exists n such that 2^(2^ceil(log2(n))) > c * 2^n. Let's consider only n = 2^k + 1 for some integer k > 1; this is our right, since we are not trying to prove the statement for all n. The desired inequality becomes

```
2^(2^ceil(log2(2^k + 1))) >? c * 2^(2^k + 1).
```

We simplify the left hand side.

```
ceil(log2(2^k + 1)) = k + 1
2^(2^ceil(log2(2^k + 1))) = 2^(2^(k + 1)).
```

The desired inequality is

```
2^(2^(k + 1)) >? c * 2^(2^k + 1).
```

This inequality is equivalent to

```
2^(2^(k + 1) - 2^k - 1) = 2^(2^k - 1) >? c.
2^k - 1 >? log2(c)
2^k >? log2(c) + 1
k >? log2(log2(c) + 1).
```

The choice of k (and thus n) is now obvious; work backward through the inequality to show the desired inequality, so the function is not O(2^n).

Comment: I just wanted to say, that the importance of choice of `2^k + 1` should be stressed. This is a great way to deal with `ceil` as it forces it to always round up. It is crucial for further analysis. I made a mistake in by thinking that you ban bind `2^(2^ceil(log2(n)))` by `2^(2^log2(n))` and `2^(2^(log2(n)+1))`. For cases when `ceil` would not round up it's the same as `O(2^n)`, by carefully choosing `n` and eliminating cases where `2^ceil(log2(n))) = n`, you rule out the "optimistic cases", it always is `2n`, which makes difference for `2^f(n)`.

Comment: For clarity, for cases where `ceil` rounds up it behaves like `2^(2n)` and `O(2^n)` < `O(2^(2n))`. By the way could you prove this for non-integer `k`, so that `ceil(log2(2^k + 1)) = k + 1` assumption would not be clear? I find it interesting that you can choose particular values for the function and it asymptotic behavior is different. There is one weakness I noticed, you kind of violated the constraint posed by OP i.e. "*n is a power of 2*" you say "*it's a power of 2 plus 1*", which fine for general analysis, but it seems to change a lot for the particular case.

Answer (score 0):

2^(2^ceil(log2(n))) < 2^(2^(log2(n)+1)) = 2^(2n)